# Use properties to refer derived class member variables to base class member variables

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

My current code looks a little like this.

```
class BaseClass2
{
    public List<BaseClass1> list { get; set; }
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass2
{
    public DerivedClass1A objA { get; set; }
    public DerivedClass1B objB  { get; set; }
}
```

What i have is a DerivedClass2 where i know the types of the list in the base class and i know there will be two types of DerivedClass1A and DerivedClass1B.

I could create new variables as above but i'd prefer not to use the memory and cleverly access and set the original list, how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass2
{
    public DerivedClass1A objA
    {
        get
        {
            return (DerivedClass1A)base.list[0];
        }
        set
        {
            base.list[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public DerivedClass1B objB
    {
        get
        {
            return (DerivedClass1B)base.list[1];
        }
        set
        {
            base.list[1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That isn't good design though... Why would you have that list? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure that there will be only 2 elements in the list?

Comment: @JakubKonecki No. I say this is a bad thing. But this is an example of how to do what I understood he wants.

Comment: Yes 2 elements. This is what i was getting at, just need to think if this fits exactly what i want....

Comment: Will these properties have seperate stored data values then? If not is there a way to do that?

Comment: They won't have stored data values. They will access the elements at the list property of the base class, when called get or set. You can try this with debugging and setting break points at the beginning of the set and get to see nicely how this goes.

Comment: In answer to your question, i could do with the list to keep my BaseClass2 fairly abstract and to enable other possibilities in future development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics:

```
class BaseClass2<T>
  T : BaseClass1
{
    public List<T> list { get; set; }
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass2<BaseClass1>
{
    public DerivedClass1A objA { get; set; }
    public DerivedClass1B objB  { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you just want to get a subclasses from your list you can use `TypeOf()` method:

```
baseClass2Instance.list.TypeOf<DerivedClass1A>();
```

Comment: That doesn't change his situation at all.

Comment: I agree. I suppose that one of our answers will help. Either way, if he tells us what the situation really is, I bet there's a better way to do it.